# Incoming call notification for RingCentral

Tags: push-notification, ringcentral

I am developing a C# application to notify user in real time for the incoming call. I am able to get SMS notifications successfully but not able to get notifications for the calls.

I am using [RingCentral C# Github](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp) to develop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider upgrading to the RingCentral C# Client SDK - https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get SMS notifications and want call notifications, you just need to modify your event filters and subscribe for presence events. A list of events is available in the API Reference. I've added a few deep links to call events below.

- API Reference: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/

Account Presence Event

```
/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/presence
```

- https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefGetAccountPresenceEvent

Extension Presence Events

```
/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/presence
/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/presence/line/presence
```

- https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefGetExtensionPresenceEvent

Detailed Extension Presence Events

```
/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true
/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/presence/line/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true
```

- https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefGetDetailedExtensionPresenceEvent

Extension Presence Line Event

```
/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/presence/line
```

- https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefGetExtensionPresenceLineEvent

Missed Calls Event

```
/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/missed-calls
```

- https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#MissedCallsEvent

Comment: How to setup listeners for these events on my website?